# Jquery insert function params into selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery function that helps with validation over 1 object. I need to expand it so that the function will run over 3 different objects. I am trying to define a function that takes a parameter(whichquote) to insert the appropriate object in the function. Here is my code. What I am doing wrong? I assume I do not have the selector correct as the code works if I put it in.

Original Function that works:

```
  var depends = function() {
      var selectorD = $("input[name^='lead[quote_diamonds_attributes]'], select[name^='lead[quote_diamonds_attributes]']");
      var vals = '';
      selectorD.not(':eq(0)').each(function () {
          vals += $(this).val();
      });

      return vals.length > 0;
  };
```

Function I am trying to create that allows me to use it on other objects. This currently does not work.

```
 var depends = function(whichquote) {
      var selectorD = $("input[name^='lead[+ whichquote +]'], select[name^='lead[+ whichquote +]']");**
      var vals = '';
      selectorD.not(':eq(0)').each(function () {
          vals += $(this).val();
      });

      return vals.length > 0;
  };
```

I think the problem is with my concating in the var selectorD but cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

Comment: I think you're just missing the quotation marks, try this:
var selectorD = $("input[name^='lead["+ whichquote +"]'], select[name^='lead["+ whichquote +"]']");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector isn't actually inputting `whichquote` because the string concatenation is incorrect.

Try

`var selectorD = $("input[name^='lead[" + whichquote + "]'], select[name^='lead[" + whichquote +"]']");`

Comment: I tried that with no success. It seems like it should. How would I call the function: depends("quote_diamonds_attributes") or depends(quote_diamonds_attributes)? I have tried both.

Comment: With quotes I believe. try to log out selectorD after your assignement.

Comment: Yes, it is with quotes. I adjusted some other code and now it seems to be working. Not sure why. I appreciate your help.